# crop and convert to pdf adds unwanted margin

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick, png

I have a few PNG files that I want to print in a certain scale. For that I want to convert each of them to (DIN-A4 sized) PDF and crop into multiple pages. So far I've used this command:

```
convert -resize 283% -crop 500x790 -verbose in.png out.pdf
```

with the following output:

```
in.png PNG 412x556 412x556+0+0 8-bit sRGB 256c 5.69KB 0.010u 0:00.010
in.png=>out.pdf[0] PNG 412x556=>500x790 1166x1573+0+0 8-bit sRGB 433KB 0.290u 0:00.269
```

but in the generated PDF the pages are not DIN-A4 sized (they are as big as if I didn't include the `-crop`-option) and contain large white areas.

Edit: I also tried the `+repage`-option (before `-verbose`) but the output and result were the same.

Comment: try adding `+repage -page a4 ` and putting the .png at the start.

Comment: @meuh You might want to collect the points by adding that as an answer.